# How to build a querypacket query to also return pdf files from SharePoint 2010

Tags: query, spquery

I am very new to using querypacket search queries, so please provide info useful to a complete beginner.

I have query like below.  The issue is that the existing query will return me all documents that are of .txt or .docx file types but not .pdf file types.

I need to be able to search by file name or type, so if I am searching for a .txt file, then the line below will look like

```
<QueryText type="STRING" language="en-us">.txt ...
```

If I try to search for .docx, the same line will look like

```
<QueryText type="STRING" language="en-us">.docx...
```

And these both return me all documents of txt or docs types.  But if I search for .pdf then the line looks like:

```
<QueryText type="STRING" language="en-us">.pdf....
```

and that fails to return any pdf file.

Say my pdf file was named "**Some file I am interested in.pdf**".  My search query should return that file if I search by "**Some**" or "**file**" or "**interested**" or "**.pdf**" or "**pdf**", etc.

Here is my query

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<QueryPacket Revision="1000">
    <Query domain="QDomain">
        <SupportedFormats>
            <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format>
        </SupportedFormats>
        <Context>
            <QueryText type="STRING" language="en-us">.pdf (Path:"http://my-sp2010/sites/ME/LOC" IsDocument:"true" (ContentClass:"STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary" OR ContentClass:"STS_ListItem_1302" OR ContentTypeId:"0x0101*") NOT(FileExtension:"aspx"))</QueryText>
        </Context>
        <Range>
            <StartAt>1</StartAt>
            <Count>100</Count>
        </Range>
        <EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming>
        <TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>
        <IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>
        <ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior>
        <IncludeRelevanceResults>false</IncludeRelevanceResults>
        <IncludeSpecialTermResults>false</IncludeSpecialTermResults>
        <IncludeHighConfidenceResults>false</IncludeHighConfidenceResults>
    </Query>
    <QueryOptions>
        <IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls>
    </QueryOptions>
</QueryPacket>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```
<QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'>test filetype:pdf</QueryText>
```

Comment: but I do not want to query only for pdf files